# Retrieve ValueForKey BOOL value

Tags: ios, key-value

I mark some objects as inactive

```
[apIndicators[i] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isActive"];
```

Later I set some of them as active. Then I have to check all inactive objects left in 'NSMutableArray'.

I have to do that in for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < apCount; i++) {
     if [apIndicators[i] valueForKey:@"isActive"]) { //the problem is here
          //do some stuff with object
     }
}
```

How can I get YES or NO value of every object in array?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
BOOL active = [[apIndicators[i] valueForKey:@"isActive"] boolValue];

if (active){
    // do whatever
}
```

If those apIndicators are all NSDictionaries you could use the fast enumerator to simplify the loop quite a bit as well.

```
for (NSDictionary *apIndicator in yourArray){
    BOOL active = [[apIndicator valueForKey:@"isActive"] boolValue];
    if (active){
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that helped me to understand that the problem was in my array.